Can I send data from Azure monitor / fabric to metabase
We currently use azure monitor to monitor our system. I want to export this data to metabase, any idea how
PS Yes I know power BI is easy but the cost is just too much

can you provide what is your approach so far and ERROR details if any for further investigation with respect to your ask

I have googled this and could find nothing, we could find a mechanism to send from metabase to power bi but nothing about the other way around

https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/Connect-Power-BI-directly-to-Metabase/td-p/2457122
I found this Can you check if this helps you?

To connect Azure Monitor to Metabase, you need to export your Azure Monitor logs and data to a data source compatible with Metabase.
This is can be done by setting up a data pipeline to transfer Azure Monitor data into a Metabase-supported database,
such as a SQL server or data warehouse. Metabase can then connect directly to this source for visualizing the data on dashboards.
Thanks to @Utkarsh Pal for the solution Azure Monitor Export to a SQL Server.
Once you have the data ready in the SQL database. The below steps will help you configure to Metabase.

Set up the VNET (Virtual Network).
Create the application database (PostgreSQL).
Establish the private endpoint connection.
Deploy the web application (Metabase).

Reference: Running Metabase on Microsoft Azure

Symon Turner I found some info on the internet can you please check if the above solution helped you?
